# I accidentally put about 3/4 of a quart to much of oil in my car

Tags: oil, car

Would this do any damage to my car? It is a 3.8 v6 Pontiac Grand Prix.

Answer (score 1):

3/4 of a quart will probably not cause damage, but it may cause some foaming if the crank is dipping into the sump.  I wouldn't worry.

You could crack the drain plug and drip out that amount if it bothers you.

Comment: If the crank is dipping into the oil - it can make it harder to start...

Comment: True dat.  But I doubt it on a 'Merican 3.8 liter sump.

Comment: And burning a tad blue out the exhaust pipe at times.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend checking the level on the dip stick, a little over wont hurt.
but ultimately the correct answer is to drain the oil to the correct level.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: I've never tried this myself.

Is it close to being time to change the oil filter? Depending on its position, you should be able to spin it off without losing much more than the oil contained within (which should be ~0.5-0.75 litre). Replace it with a new (empty) one and run the engine for a minute or two then recheck the oil level.

[image]
  <sub>The oil filter seems to be a horizontal mount so it's going to be messy. However, it appears to be sufficiently above the sump that you won't lose any more than the oil in the existing filter.</sub>

Depending on whether your oil filler tube goes into the block or into an OHV cover, you might be able to syphon off a litre or so through it.

Edit:

[image]
  <sub>Looks like you add oil through the valve cover so you can scratch option 2.</sub>